# Failing to create a controller MVC/C#

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, controller, ninject

Every so often I would get an error of:

> An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'MyProject.Controllers.*ControllerName*'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.

I know some people have had a similar issue, but with my problem it just seems to happen at random times. For example it may occur when trying to create `MyProject.Controllers.EmailController`, while I may be hitting the page through a javascript call every 60 seconds to check for any email notifications the error won't happen every 60 seconds.

The puzzling thing is, this happens to many controllers and while it doesn't happen everyday - when the errors do occur, they seem to happen at the same time. For example today we had 15 errors at 6am.

For this example - the Email Controller Model contains:

```
private readonly IAggregator _aggregator;

public EmailController(IAggregator aggregator)
{
    _aggregator = aggregator;
}
```

In global.asax.cs we have a dependency injection method, as shown below:

```
public class MvcApplication : NinjectHttpApplication 
{
    protected override IKernel CreateKernel()
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();
        kernel.Load(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        kernel.Bind<IAggregator>().To<Aggregator>();
        return kernel;
    }
```